# Error when trying to connect to TFS 2012 Express server and view in browser

Tags: iis, tfs

I have installed team foundation server 2012 express and am wanting to connect through visual studio 2010 ultimate.

TFS seems to have installed ok but when I try to connect I get the following error:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this team foundation server:
http://<servername>:8080/tfs.

possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the team foundation server is incorrect.
- The team Foundation server is offline
- The password has expired or is incorrect.
```

Now when I try to browse to the url provided i get the following web browser error:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll" failed
```

I read that this issue can be caused by a faulty install of .net 4 as detailed [here](http://dailydevscoveries.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/calling-loadlibraryex-on-isapi-filter.html)  but i think this is unlikely as Ive been programming/using .net 4 for development for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked..... Looks like the automated setup of TFS 2012 Express didnt setup something right.

[Link](http://www.codertakeout.com/v/35674/4O9BY)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add complete tfs server path and port number instead of relying on "connection details" box in "Add Team Foundation Server" dialog box. :8080/tfs OR maybe you've wrote this address: :8080/tfs/ so just omit the "/" at the end of your address.